# ¿Enviar datos por POST desde php mediante cURL?

Tags: php, post, curl

Estoy intentando enviar datos a una API externa, el problema es que cuando abro la consola en chrome o inspecciono cualquier elemento, se muestran los valores `hidden` del form que son las claves del API, así que intente esto con `Curl`:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init('https://apiurl.com/');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "ApiKey=$ak&merchantId=$mi&accountId=$ac");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,false);
$respuesta = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
?>
```

Ahora, tengo 3 preguntas:

1. Entiendo que esta función se realiza automáticamente, entonces, ¿Cómo lo hago con un `<input type="submit">` o un `<button>`?
2. ¿Es seguro enviar los datos de esta forma?
3. ¿Qué otra forma de enviar estos datos sugieren?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que harías es ejecutar el curl en un archivo que llames al pulsar el botón, ya sea tipo submit y funcione como cuando envías un formulario, o bien ejecutando un ajax en el evento onclick o onsubmit. Depende de si quieres mantener al usuario en el archivo actual o llevarle al archivo destino donde lo ejecutas, eso lo marcara la lógica de tu proyecto.

Es un método seguro y una buena forma de enviar los datos a la api.

Ejemplo: asocias una función al elemento clickable y le envías por `AJAX` al archivo donde haces el curl, de modo que sólo se ejecuta al hacer click. La apikey está en ese archivo, así que no es visible para el usuario.

```
<div onclick="enviar();">enviar</div>

<script>
function enviar() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "", //archivo php con el curl
    type: "post",
    data: //si necesitas enviar algún dato desde aquí para la ejecución del curl
  });
}
</script>
```

Si desde la API recibes resultados que quieres mostrar los puedes recoger en el `success` del `AJAX`.

Comment: podrías darme el ejemplo de como harías con un `onclick`

Comment: Claro, ahora edito.

Answer (score 1):

1. Los campos "submit" se envían como [name del campo]="Value del botón". Por defecto, si no le damos ningún value a un campo submit, éste dependerá de lo que le asigne el navegador. Probablemente "Enviar consulta" o algo similar. Lo más práctico para botones "submit" es simplemente comprobar que hayan sido setteados via name, independientemente de su "contenido"
2. Así deberías ocultar la api a tus clientes y haciendo las peticiones via https debería ser seguro
3. Si pretendes ocultar la api a tus clientes, no se me ocurre mucho más que puedas hacer que mover las peticiones al servidor. Respecto a curl, hay otras alternativas como http://guzzle.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ o http://phphttpclient.com/. Aquí se discuten algunas de ellas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9802788/call-a-rest-api-in-php

Comment: con respecto al punto 1 de la respuesta lo que sugieres es que envíe a otra pagina que haga el `post` mediante `curl` i verifique mediante un `isset`

Comment: agradecería que ejemplificaran mediante codigo